# Add a constraint to all columns in all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

In SQL-Server is there quick way to add a constraint to all columns in all tables in an empty database?

> I want to add constraints to all columns to prevent users from using leading/trailing spaces and empty strings. 
>   Here are the constraints I want to add:
>   `RIGHT([ColumnName],1) <> ' '` && `LEFT([ColumnName],1) <> ' '` && `([ColumnName]<>'')`

I realize that you can add a single constraint to a column but what do you do if the database got lots of tables with even more columns, its going to take a while to add single constraints to all the columns. I am looking for a more efficient solution

Comment: Just a passing thought... Perhaps `ascii(right([ColumnName],1))>32` to avoid the dreaded control characters like CRLF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not gonna dive into **WHY** you need to do it on every column in DB, it seems odd, but I leave that to you.

Here is how you do it (you didn't spec what constraint tho)

Make a temp table out of every table-column from that table combination

- Iterate over that table picking the 1st one
- Set your constraint using table and column name, maybe getting some additional stuff as well, depends on what constrain it is
- After you added the constraint, delete that record from temp table so another one becomes top 1.
- Keep doing above 2 bullets until tamp table is empty

This has been tested on SQL server, adjust the code if you need for other DBMS. But the principle is the same:

```
     select
        o.name as Tab,c.name as Col
     into #temp
        from sys.columns            c
            inner join sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
        where  type = 'U' -- only user defined
               and (t.name = 'varchar' or t.name = 'nvarchar') -- only columns with this datatypes
        order by o.name,c.column_id

    -- select * from #temp

    DECLARE @tab nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @col nvarchar(max)

    while ((select count(*) from #temp) > 0)
      BEGIN
        set @tab = (select top 1 Tab from #temp)
        set @col = (select top 1 Col from #temp)
        -- add your constraint here
        -- select @tab, @col
        delete from #temp where Tab = @tab and Col = @col
      END

    drop table #temp
```

Uncomment the commented parts to see selected table-column values or see how it iterates.

EDIT 1: Added the `where type = 'U'` to get from `system.objects` only user-defined ones.

EDIT 2: Expanded the where clause, now it only takes varchar and nvarchar columns from user made tables

Comment: It would be a good idea to put a where clause that will only get varchar and nvarchar fields, and also does not get any system tables also

Comment: He changed the question after I posted the answer. It used to explicit say ALL tables and didn't state which constraints.

Comment: I have read the original question and my comment still stands. There is no sense in trying to eliminate spaces in other fieldtypes, and certainly not in system tables and views. Dont get me wrong, I think your answer is good, it just needs some fine tuning

Comment: It does make sense what you said, no argue there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea to add this type of constraints everywhere in the database. I think users don't add data to the database directly, So you should handle this in the area from where the data is added to the tables or in the presentation layer.

Comment: Isn't constraints & validations best used on the database back-end? If I don't add it in the back end there is a chance that a 'rogue' front end form might slip in empty strings.

Comment: I always put as much on the database as possible, and then again in the front end. Its double work but its the only way to be sure

Comment: Definitely you can use constraints in the back end and they are introduced because they are necessary and useful. But i told about the type of constraints you are looking for. You can always apply validations in the front end. You can take a look about the sql server constraints [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862(v=sql.105).aspx)